# How can i get all the category under nested document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following json object in mongo db, there are around 300 objects in the document, what is the query to retrieve all the **`category`** under ticket.seating,

```
 {   "_id": "58a1ddcb8850c027298c4dc8",   "name": "Listing 1",  
 "description": "",   "ticket": {
     "amount": 2,
     "type": "electronic",
     "splitType": 2,
     "seating": [
       {
         "category": 1,
         "section": 2,
         "row": 2
       },
       {
        "category": 3,
         "section": "uiui",
         "row": 33
       }
     ]   },   "metadata": {
     "user": {},
     "event": {},
     "venue": {}   },   "listingId": "aabb1cb6-4e79-4d48-9451-e5247230d397" }
```

**Expected output:**

1,3

Comment: please add the expected output

Comment: @felix added above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MongoDB Distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) function for this. As shown in sample below

```
db.getCollection('collection_name').distinct("ticket.seating.category");
```

It will give you all distinct categories in array like [1,3]

Comment: how can i do with mongoose?

Comment: Instead of db.getCollection('collection_name') use mongoose model.

Eg - Ticket is mongoose model, 
Ticket.distinct("ticket.seating.category",{/* any other condition you want to mention*/})

Answer (score 2):

this should do the trick

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind:"$ticket.seating"
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:null,
         category:{
            $push:"$ticket.seating.category"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : null, "category" : [ 1, 3 ] }
```

Comment: returns 0, the document name is _listing_seller

Comment: @user2280016 you mean the collection name ?

Comment: @felix I think it is better to use distinct method than unwind and group.

Comment: @PuneetSingh yes this is definitely the way to go, it would be way more efficient!